# How do you include and call multiple functions in one PHP script?

Tags: php, amazon-mws

I am writing an Amazon MWS script that needs to include multiple PHP files and run functions contained in those files.

Each function runs fine from its own respective PHP file, but only the first function runs. The second function, no matter what order I use, throws a Fatal Error about the parameters I am passing through it.

> **Fatal error:** Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Unable to construct from provided data. Please be sure to pass associative array or DOMElement'

Here are the first two functions I am trying to run:

```
// Initialize and run ListInboundShipments.
require_once 'ListInboundShipments.php';
// Set status array and timeframe criteria for filtering shipments
$shipmentStatusList = new FBAInboundServiceMWS_Model_ShipmentStatusList();
$shipmentStatusList->setMember(array('WORKING','SHIPPED','IN_TRANSIT','DELIVERED','CHECKED_IN','RECEIVING','CLOSED','CANCELLED','DELETED','ERROR'));
$updatedAfter = date('Y-m-d', mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m")-1, date("d"),   date("Y")));
$updatedBefore = date('Y-m-d');

// Pass filter criteria into $request array
$request->setShipmentStatusList($shipmentStatusList);
$request->setLastUpdatedAfter($updatedAfter);
$request->setLastUpdatedBefore($updatedBefore);

// Create XML document of shipments.
$shipmentXML = invokeListInboundShipments($service, $request);

// Parse the new XML document.
$shipments = new SimpleXMLElement($shipmentXML);
$shipmentArray = array();
foreach ($shipments->ListInboundShipmentsResult->ShipmentData->member as $member) {
    // Create array of all shipments.
    $shipmentArray[] = array(
        "ShipmentId"=>$member->ShipmentId,
        "ShipmentStatus"=>$member->ShipmentStatus
    );
}

// Destroy variables to get a clean slate.
unset($service); unset($request);

// Save token and run through ListInboundShipmentsByNextToken until
// it does not return a token.
$token = (string)$shipments->ListInboundShipmentsResult->NextToken;
while ($token != null) {
    require_once 'ListInboundShipmentsByNextToken.php';
    $request->setNextToken($token);
    echo print_r($request);

    // Create new XML document.
    $shipmentXML = invokeListInboundShipmentsByNextToken($service, $request);
    $shipments = new SimpleXMLElement($shipmentXML);

    // Use XML document to create array of all shipments.
    foreach ($shipments->ListInboundShipmentsResult->ShipmentData->member as $member) {
        $shipmentArray[] = array(
            "ShipmentId"=>$member->ShipmentId,
            "ShipmentStatus"=>$member->ShipmentStatus
        );
    }
    $token = $shipments->ListInboundShipmentsResult->NextToken;
}
```

The `echo print_r($request)` statement shows me that `$request` is indeed an associative array. I thought maybe the error was being caused by conflicting variables (each function uses $request and $service), so I tried using `unset()` in between calling them.

Comment: If `$request` is an associative array, you can't call methods like `$request->setNextToken()`. That requires `$request` to be an object. But you did `unset($request)`, so how is `$request` set to anything at all?

Comment: @Barmar: `$request` is created in the files run by `require_once`. But you are right that `$request` is an object. Maybe that is where my problem lies. It is an object containing multiple associative arrays. Should it be an array of arrays instead?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `require_once` in the `while` loop. It only executes the file the first time through the loop. The second time, it realizes that the file was already executed, so it doesn't execute it again. Use `require` instead.

```
while ($token != null) {
    require 'ListInboundShipmentsByNextToken.php';
    $request->setNextToken($token);
    echo print_r($request);

    // Create new XML document.
    $shipmentXML = invokeListInboundShipmentsByNextToken($service, $request);
    $shipments = new SimpleXMLElement($shipmentXML);

    // Use XML document to create array of all shipments.
    foreach ($shipments->ListInboundShipmentsResult->ShipmentData->member as $member) {
        $shipmentArray[] = array(
            "ShipmentId"=>$member->ShipmentId,
            "ShipmentStatus"=>$member->ShipmentStatus
        );
    }
    $token = $shipments->ListInboundShipmentsResult->NextToken;
}
```

Using an include file for code that needs to be executed repeatedly like this is unusual design. Normally you just define functions in include files, or use them to initialize global variables (e.g. database parameters). So the normal way would be to define a function in the include file, and then call that function each time through the loop, rather than including the file in the loop.

Comment: Sorry, I think my question was unclear. I am using `require_once()` multiple times to initialize multiple files. The file is certainly being executed, as I can see from the output. @vonOak: Good point. I made the change.

Comment: I'm talking about the `require_once` in the `while` loop. It only executes the first time through the loop.

Comment: Oh, I see. Yes, you are right. I moved it out of the loop. Thank you.

Comment: Doesn't it need to assign a new `$request` each time through the loop?

Comment: I'm just guessing, since you haven't shown what the file does.

Comment: it does, but the only part that needs to be changed is the `$token` value.